"Bad" valid edge contractions
In this paper, an edge contraction of a simplicial complex $\Gamma$ is defined as the operation of removing the neighborhood $N_e\Gamma$ of the edge $e=\{0,1\}$ and identifying $N_0\partial N_e\Gamma$ and $N_1\partial N_e\Gamma$. The edge contraction is called valid if the result is again a simplicial complex.
I am very new to this field and have trouble visualising things.
Question:
Is there a simple example of a geometric simplicial complex that is no longer geometric after performing a valid edge contraction?
Why I am asking:
My background is that I want to understand where, in the proof of "Kind-of Fary's theorem" in Adiprasito and Patáková, the interpretation of complexes as geometric ones fails when applied to PL embeddings into $\mathbb{R}^d$. See also this question.

Is it intentional that "this paper" and "Adiprasito and Patáková" both point to the same paper?

you can take a triangle, that is, three vertices connected by three edges. If you contract one of the edges, then you would obtain two vertices, connected by two edges, which is not allowed in simplicial complexes :)
Regards, Karim

Thanks for the answer. But that wouldn't be a valid contraction by definition, would it? I was looking for a geometric simplicial complex such that contracting an edge results in a simplicial complex that is no longer geometric, if something like that exists.

I see. However, you have to keep in mind that all simplicial complexes are geometric (they can all be realized in a geometric way)

I don't think this is possible.
If I understand the question correctly you want a simplicial complex embedded into $\mathbb R^d$ such that after a valid edge contraction such an embedding no longer exists.
Looking at the paper, they say that an edge contraction is only valid if it's not the edge of a triangulated subcomplex that is homeomorphic to a sphere.
Now if this is the case one can do a homotopy on the image of an embedding to contract this edge and get another embedding of the complex with the edge contracted.
